# Pulseaudio works at 100 percent at all time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

My headphones started to rattle recently. Then I opened pulse audio volume control I noticed that blue line indicating loudness of sound is always stuck at highest and it doesn't matter how much I will lower sound, it stay at highest point. It is the same with build in Realtek sound card and with creative sound card and if I enable or disable pulse equalizer. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: How is sound volume set in ALSA? Run `alsamixer` in a terminal.

Comment: It is at 70, changing it doesn't help in any way

Comment: What, if you change user or a guest account? How is sound there?

Comment: I tried guest and it is the same.

Comment: You can **try** if [removing the module-device-restore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168107/system-volume-setting-muted-when-headphones-unplugged-but-normal-with-headphone) resolves your issue. It may but if not, don't change your default settings, please.

Comment: hmm, I found that my index is 0, but then I tape `pacmd unload-module 0` it gives me invalid module index. I tried other modules, all give invalid module index

Comment: This is not what is expected in a default setup. Sorry, I have no more idea then.

Comment: if i will find a fix, I will post it back here

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like I fix it. And all it took to delete .pulse audio in home folder and hit `killall pulseaudio`. There is no more rattle. You can mark as solved, in case anyone else will face similar problem and search in here.

Comment: Good you found your solution. That's what I suspected when asking for guest account. It is extremely weird that an issue from settings in your account should affect other accounts.